# Good method for huge assignment problem on mathematical optimization

Tags: probability, optimization

I am working on some assignment problem of mathematical optimization.

when the number of assignment increase, it takes more time to solve formulation with gurobi or something.
Does any theoretical method exist to fasten?
( I am using a commercial solver, gurobi. Some rough idea like splitting into few groups is ok for me too( of course it will not be "optimized solution" but is ok for me as long as I can know how much it is not optimized)

any idea or link for paper would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't get any answers here, you could ask mods to migrate to https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Later posted at https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353953/177408